# Open Native Apps in WebApp net::ERR-UNKNOWN-URL-SCHEME

Tags: android, html

I'm having a problem with my webapp. With chrome, the spotify and whatsapp floating icons open their respective apps, but in the webapp (a webview of the page) i get this error:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAtFw.png)

> net::ERR-UNKNOWN-URL-SCHEME

This is the code of the floating icons in the page

```
<div style=position:fixed;top:50%;margin-top:100px;right:20px;z-index:999999999999999999>
    <a href="https://wa.me/541123609964"target=_blank>
        <img src={(GBP_URLPICTUREFILES)}icowsflotante2.png>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: "_webapp (a webview of the page)_": It's a bit unclear. Did you make an Android app with a webview, that opens your web app?

Comment: @GinoMempin yeah. It is a webview with the url of my website, that simple

Comment: OK, so, you have a WebView in your application, and in the webview you are displaying some HTML that contains an image which is part of a link.  It looks like you want to go to your own website at http://wa.me?  Is that to display some content there in your webview?  You mentioned spotify and whatsapp, do you want to open another app if the user clicks on your http://wa.me link?  If so, which app?  One of your own?  We need that level of detail before we can really help you.  Otherwise, we're just guessing at what you need!

Comment: It could be complaining about src={(GBP_URLPICTUREFILES)}icowsflotante2.png, I've never seen that kind of syntax in HTML before.  Where did you come up with that?

Comment: @MichaelDougan i use an ERP and that is a url generator in my system.

Comment: @MichaelDougan i want to open whatsapp after touching the whatsapp floating icon, spotify after touching spotify and telephone after touching the telephone action. Like if i were using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, to start a call after clicking on a link in your WebView, you would first create a link with this type of scheme:

```
<a href=\"tel:8056542739\">(805) 654-2739.</a>
```

Then, in your code, you would override shouldOverrideUrlLoading() like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url)
           {

            if (url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("geo:") || url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                           Uri.parse(url));

                startActivity(intent);

                return true; 

            } else if (url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                startActivity(sendIntent);

                return true;

             } else if (url.startsWith("spotify:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(
                              "spotify:album:0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj"));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER,
                Uri.parse("android-app://" + context.getPackageName()));

                startActivity(intent);

                return true;

             }

             return false;
           }
       });
```

This override sends anything with a tel:, mailto:, http: or https: scheme to a new 'intent' with ACTION_VIEW, which means that Android will try to find one or more apps installed on the device that can handle that kind of URI.  The Phone app can handle tel: so, that gets called if your link has that scheme in it, like my example.  Same thing for the mailto: scheme, that should open your e-mail composing app.  For whatsapp and spotify, they both have schemes such as whatsapp: and spotify: which can be handled slightly differently.  See one possible way above for that.